# Would z-index affect elements from being "hovered" over?

Tags: html, css, dom

If I have a `div` that has another `div` beneath it, would the underlying `div`'s `hover` state be activated when the cursor is over the top `div`? Assume that the top `div` has a `z-index` of 5 and the other `div`'s `z-index` is 1.

Comment: maybe fiddle or some code that you tried can help us to understand the problem exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Take the following code as an example:

HTML:

```
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
div#one {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
}
div#two {
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The hover never activates on `div#one` when `div#two` is hovered in the overlapping area.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yff7Q/

Answer (score 1):

Just whipped together something quick.

An element within another element with `:hover` will work (even on negative `z-index`).

An element outside the element with the negative `z-index` won't work.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/vCIwz/) | [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVaTp/)

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="inside">
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="outside"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  position:relative;
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  opacity:.4;
  background:red;
}

.outside, .inside{
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-5;
}

.outside{
  top:400px;
}

.inside:hover{
  opacity:0;
}

.outside:hover{
  opacity:0;
}
```